# Wheel listener get position after the event

Tags: javascript

I have a wheel event and in it I am getting the scrollY position:

```
getY(e){
    let y = window.scrollY
}
```

but it is giving me the current y not the one that the page is going to end at after the event. How can I get or calculate the upcoming scrollY?

Comment: Buy a magic 8 ball? (scrolling can be prevented by the user)

Comment: m not sure whether putting this in setTimeout will solve the problem.

Comment: @Kaiido But isn't there a way to calculate it with the delta?

Comment: No as I said, the user can prevent it, say by scrolling in the other direction.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but if the user scroll at the other direction the function will be executed again? So it will get the current location at the time of the new function and the next delta

Comment: Yes and at the time you "calculated" the future, you were wrong. If you want something that sometimes work, try Math.random()

Answer (score 1):

Do not use wheel event, use the `scroll` event instead, it will give you the correct outcome.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll(){
  console.log(window.scrollY);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

But if you wanna know the `deltaX` and `deltaY` every time when user scroll, here's the way:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel);

function onWheel(e){
  const {deltaX, deltaY} = e;
  console.log(deltaX, deltaY);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
```